# How to specify the directory for file-exists/delete-file/byte-compile-file?

Tags: directories, byte-compilation

I thought it would be great to save a Elisp file (in my init), and it compiles automatically a byte-compile Elisp-file.

So I wrote a function for this.

```
    (defun remove-elc-and-compile-on-save ()
      "If you're saving an elisp file, likely the .elc is no longer valid. And automatically byte-recompile this file whenever it's saved."
      (interactive)
      (if (file-exists-p (concat buffer-file-name "c"))
          (delete-file (concat buffer-file-name "c"))
        nil)
      (byte-compile-file buffer-file-name)
      )

    (add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook 
              (lambda () 
                (add-hook 'after-save-hook 'remove-elc-and-compile-on-save nil 'make-it-local)))
```

For example, the directory structure where my Elisp files are: `C:\foobar\Emacs\setup-foobar.el.` (It's a Windows structure).

It works perfectly. However, my Emacs directory with the Elips-files will be spoiled with the compiled `.elc`-files all over the place. So I thought to move the `.elc`-files to a specific directory.

For example, the directory structure where my Elisp files are: `C:\foobar\Emacs\setup-foobar.el.` (It's a Windows structure).

Then I would like to move the `.elc` files to `C:\foobar\Emacs\setup\setup-foobar.el.` When I checked the documentation of the functions `file-exists-p`, `delete-file`, `byte-compile-file`, there is no optional parameter available to specify the path where the delete/compilation operations should occur. They're executed in the same directory as the `buffer-file-name`.

I tried another ways like:

```
(byte-compile-file (concat "C:/foobar/Emacs/setup/" buffer-file-name))
```

But it didn't worked out, and it's not applicable for the `file-exists-p` and `delete-file` functions.

So I'm wondering in which way I could specify the path where the operations should be executed, instead in the same directory as the buffer?

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but, typically, the solution to this is to hide the uninteresting files rather than to move them elsewhere. A way to achieve this is typically by placing a directory local settings as described here: http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Directory-Variables.html

Comment: There is no reason to delete a *.elc file if you are going to recompile the *.el to create an updated *.elc. The new *.elc will replace the old one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. I agree with @wvxvw's comment: You don't need to move the *.elc files; it is enough to not look at them. ;-)  You can hide them from a Dired listing, for example.
2. But if you really want to have byte-compiling automatically put the *.elc result in a different directory then you can set variable `byte-compile-dest-file-function` to a function that is similar to `byte-compile-dest-file` but which uses a different directory.  Something like this:

```el
(setq byte-compile-dest-file-function #'my-byte-compile-dest-file)

(defvar my-bytecomp-dir "/PATH/TO/YOUR/ELC/DIRECTORY/")

(defun my-byte-compile-dest-file (filename)
  "Like `byte-compile-dest-file', but put `*.elc' in directory `my-bytecomp-dir'."
  (setq filename  (file-name-sans-versions  (byte-compiler-base-file-name filename)))
  (expand-file-name
   (file-name-nondirectory
    (cond ((string-match emacs-lisp-file-regexp filename)
           (concat (substring filename 0 (match-beginning 0)) ".elc"))
          (t (concat filename ".elc"))))
   my-bytecomp-dir))
```

Comment: Great Drew, your solution solved my issue. I'm aware that the `.elc`-files are not visible in Helm/Dired/IDO, but I prefer to seperate these concerns. I'm somewhat suprised that you know something like this. How did you figure this out, if I might ask?

Comment: I looked at the code for `byte-compile-file`, and saw that it calls the value of `byte-compile-dest-file-function` (if non-`nil`) to do everything. The code for `my-byte-compile-file` is just the code from `byte-compile-file`, tweaked to (a) not call `byte-compile-dest-file-function` (since that is already called) and to use a different directory for the result.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explaination. It enables me to figure the things out on my own. I reallly appreciate your help in this. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. That's the idea behind this site: help users learn to "*ask Emacs*" and to help themselves.